# how to flatten, denormalize in pig

Tags: apache-pig

I'd like to create a flattened join table from the following schema

```
   titles = FOREACH programs GENERATE (px.pig.udf.PARSE_KEYWORDS(program_xml))
    AS program:
        (root_id: long, 
        ids:bag {(idtype:chararray, idvalue:chararray)}, 
        keywords:bag {(keytype:chararray,keyvalue:chararray)});
```

if the input is

```
(1, {('x','foo'),('y','bar')},{})
(2, {('x','fiz'),('y','buzz')},{})
(2, {('x','moo')},{})
...
```

The output should be something like:

```
root_id    idvalue
1          foo
1          bar
2          fiz
2          buzz
3          moo
```

How would I do that in pig?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Project first two columns.

   x = foreach titles generate root_id, ids;
2. flatten on the second column.

   y = foreach x generate root_id, FLATTEN(ids) as (idtype:chararray, idvalue:chararray);

This will give you the result in the following format:
root_id    idtype     idvalue
1          x           foo

1          y           bar

2          x           fiz

2          y           buzz

3          x           moo

Project first and third column to get the required result.

Comment: why is the intermediat eproejction X required, why doesn't the flatten work when there are other columsn in the list?

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey The relation `x` isn't needed here.  Additionally, `FLATTEN(ids) as (idtype:chararray, idvalue:chararray)` just needs to be `FLATTEN(ids)` since Pig is smart enough to find the schema from inside the bag.